# How to setup xorg to use multiseat in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xorg, lightdm, multiseat

I trying to setup multiseat on clearly installed ubuntu 14.04.02 with core i3 integrated video and nVidia GT260 video cards. 
I followed [this miltiseat instruction on wiki.ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MultiseatTeam/Instructions) and manual [Multiseat in Ubuntu 14.10](http://2buntu.com/articles/1514/multiseat-in-ubuntu-1410/)

What I did:

- Install multiseat PPA
- Not found lightdm.conf - create it and add this:

  ```
  [LightDM]
   logind-load-seats=true
   logind-check-graphical=true
  ```
- create `xorg.conf` and add this:

  ```
  Section "ServerLayout" 
          Identifier "Main Layout" 
          Screen      0  "Screen0" 
          Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0" 
  EndSection 

  Section "Monitor" 
          Identifier     "Monitor0" 
          ModelName      "LG 22EN33S-BA" 
          HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0 
          VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0 
          Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080" 
          Option         "DPMS" 
  EndSection 

  Section "Monitor" 
          Identifier     "Monitor1" 
          ModelName      "LG 22EN33S-BA" 
          HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0 
          VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0 
      Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080" 
          Option         "DPMS" 
  EndSection 

  Section "Device" 
          Identifier     "Device0" 
          Driver         "nouveau" 
          MatchSeat      "seat-1" 
  EndSection 

  Section "Device" 
          Identifier     "Device1" 
  EndSection 

  Section "Screen" 
          Identifier     "Screen0" 
          Device         "Device0" 
          Monitor        "Monitor0" 
          DefaultDepth    24 
          SubSection     "Display" 
              Depth       24 
          EndSubSection 
  EndSection  

  Section "Screen" 
          Identifier     "Screen1" 
          Device         "Device1" 
          Monitor        "Monitor1" 
          DefaultDepth    24 
          SubSection     "Display" 
              Depth       24 
          EndSubSection 
  EndSection
  ```
- attaching some mouse and keyboard to seat-1
- attaching nvidia card and frame buffer to seat-1

Reboot and ...

System on and show me on Screen1 that OS runs in low quality video mode. When i cancel error window i see  terminal on Screen0! I login and type:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Lighdm starts but only on Screen0.

What i missed in my configures? Please help me to write correct xorg.conf to my multiseat system - thank you!